# JavaScript circular dependency with a Class

Tags: javascript, circular-dependency

I have the following code.

fileA.js:

```
import Sprite from './fileB.js'; 
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

fileB.js:

```
class Sprite{
... 
draw(){ 
   context.drawImage{
   ...} 
 ...} 
 }
export default Sprite
```

I import class Sprite from fileB to fileA. But the class Sprite from fileB need a variable declared in fileA resulting in a circular dependency. Even though I found [this article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-break-a-cyclic-dependency-between-es6-modules-fd8ede198596) I'm not sure how to solve this issue.

How can I solve this circular dependency?

Comment: Please show us how you export and import these variables.

Comment: Why do you import `Sprite` in `fileA.js`?

Comment: In what order would put the code in a single file? Also why not just do that?

Comment: If you import `fileA.js` from some other file, then you can just passed the `context` variable to `Sprite` imported from fileB. I don't get the circular part here; it seems straightforward unless you left out something important.

Comment: Pass the context/canvas into the class, there is no reason why it should rely on that variable

Answer (score 0):

Pass `context` into the `Sprite` instance when you instantiate it; this will make the `Context` instance available via `this.context`:

```
class Sprite {
  constructor({ context, ...moreParams }) {
    this.context = context;
  }
  draw(...) {
    this.context.drawImage(...);
  }
}

let mySprite = Sprite({ context });
mySprite.draw(...);
```